# How can I use _ library in Angular unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, underscore.js, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to unit test a simple function in a factory, but I'm using underscorejs library in the code.

Code to test:

```
        var unpackOrderData = function(data){
        var paramsToUnpack = ["created_at", "total_price"];

        var unpackedArray = _.map(data, function(largeObj){
            return _.pick(largeObj, paramsToUnpack);
        });

        _.each(unpackedArray, convertTimeToMillis);

        _.each(unpackedArray, convertJSONToArray);

        var returnValue = [unpackedArray];
        return returnValue;
    };
```

app.js:

.constant('*',
      window.*
  )

```
    beforeEach( 
    inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, _OrderDataFactory_, ___) {
        $rootScope  = _$rootScope_;
        _ = ___;
        httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        httpBackend.whenGET('http:/localhost:1000/orders').respond(200, dataToCompare);

        orderDataFactory = _OrderDataFactory_;
    }) 
);
```

Then I'm getting the following error from karma results:
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '_.map')

Any ideas how I can inject this dependency into my tests?

Comment: `Underscore` is not an angular service to be injected. Also, I haven't seen any use of `_` in your test.

Comment: is the lodash component listed in your karma conf file?

Comment: Damn it always seems easy when you've got the answers, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should import the undescore lib at your karma.conf file

In my code I did smth like this:

```
files: [
            { pattern: 'node_modules/angular/angular.js', watched: false },
            { pattern: 'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', watched: false },
            { pattern: 'node_modules/underscore/underscore.js', watched: false },
```